# Bryant Furnace problem

Tags: heating, furnace

I have a Bryant furnace model #355CAV060100 when the thermostat is set in heat mode and on auto the heat comes on but the blower fan runs in low speed. If i switch the selector on evolution thermostat to fan on either low, med., or high the blower fan operates just fine .
My thoughts are that control board is not working correctly, was looking for some advice on what can be the cause?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the exact make and model of the thermostat.

Comment: Has this been a long-term issue or has it just started behaving this way?

Comment: Is it a two-stage furnace?  Ours will do that when it's just maintaining temperature and doesn't need to pump out a lot of heat.

Comment: Yes it is two stage but very low speed all the time  and so no air flow coming out the  vents upstairs.

Comment: It just stared this year when we turned on heat for the first time.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please? The install manual doesn't supply one...